# tomcat6 does not read environment variables

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

This is just an assumption, but I'm following the log of catalina.out and it looks like every time I would expect a value from an environment variable there is nothing. For example:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/adminLog.log (No such file or directory)` where it should go to `$CATALINA_BASE/logs/adminLog.log` and $CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat6

I've set the environment variables this webapp uses as system wide in the `/etc/environment` file. I've checked and after restarting they are still there. But tomcat insists of reading blanks.

Any ideas of why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right - Tomcat pays no attention to variables that are not set in the startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put tomcat / webapp specific environment variables into setenv.sh in tomcat's bin directory. Create one if it does not exists.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how you start Tomcat up.  Let us say you are starting as user 'test' (assuming unix machine.). Login as 'test' and check environment variables are there in your environment with the 'env' command.
If it is there then Tomcat when started from that shell, with tomcat/bin/startup.sh  will be able to read them.

Now, Tomcat will only read variables it understands. If you are setting your own, then your application needs to read them.